# Exclude folder from mobile redirect

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I plan to exclude a folder
www.mysite.com/ca-eng/pages/storesection/
 on my full website from mobile redirection and unfortunately I do not have access to .htaccess file.
My service provider charge me for every update and I used already 2 trials.

My latest version that I am prepared looks like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}!^/storesection/
RewriteRule (.*) http://mobile.mysite.com$/1 [R,L]
```

Please advise if that code will run properly.

Thank you in advance.

Full Code:

```
# stop_mobi cookie management 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} stop_mobi=yes 
RewriteRule .*- [CO=stop_mobi:yes:.mysite.com:30] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} stop_mobi=yes 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !stop_mobi=no 
RewriteRule .*- [CO=stop_mobi:yes:.mysite.com:30] 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} stop_mobi=no 
RewriteRule .*- [CO=stop_mobi:yes:.mysite.com:-30]

# mobile agents check 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Android [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} AU-MIC [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} AUDIOVOX- [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Alcatel [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} BB10 [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} BlackBerry [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Blazer [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Danger\ hiptop [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} DoCoMo/ [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Ericsson [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Googlebot-Mobile [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} MSN\ Mobile\ Proxy [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Handheld [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} HTC_HD2_T58585\ Opera [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} iPhone [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} iPod [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Klondike [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} LG- [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} LGE- [OR] 
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} \LGE\ [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} MOT- [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} NetFront [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Nokia [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} NokiaN8 [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Novarra-Vision [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Opera\ Mini [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} PalmOS [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} PalmSource [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Panasonic- [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} SAGEM- [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} SAMSUNG [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} SGH- [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} SHARP- [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} SIE- [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Samsung- [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Smartphone [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Sony [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Symbian\ OS [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} webOS [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Windows\ CE [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Windows\ Mobile [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Windows\ Phone [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} nokia [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} portalmmm [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Profile/MIDP- [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} UP.Link [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} UP.Browser [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} XV6875 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !UsableNet [NC]

# stop_mobi check 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !stop_mobi=yes 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !stop_mobi=yes

# execute redirect 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}!^/pages/storesection/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpeg|gif|bmp|png|tiff|css|js)$
RewriteRule (.*) http://mobile.mysite.com$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: What is location of your .htaccess file?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to this information :( ... I suppose it is placed in a root folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming .htaccess is placed in root you can use this rule as your very first rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/(ca-eng|ca-fre|us)/pages/storesection/
RewriteRule !\.(?:jpe?g|gif|bmp|png|tiff|css|js)$ http://mobile.mysite.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I am going to send this code to deployment to my service provider and I will let you know. :) Cheers!

Comment: It works fine if I know the absolute path on server. I have many lang versions /ca-eng/, /ca-fre/ and /us/ too. There is a way to specify only 1 time /storesection/ folder. Or I have to write   3 times : RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/ca-eng/pages/storesection/ ; RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/ca-fre/pages/storesection/ and RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/us/pages/storesection/?  Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: It can be combined in one condition using regex alternation, see updated one.

Comment: Sorry didn't get your comment.

Comment: Hi Anubhava, On my Godaddy hosting I tried to simulate my work environment hierarchy and I found that  # exclude paths
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/storesection/ works fine too. I am going to send both versions to "company" staging and I will get back to you. Thank a lot for your support!

Comment: I still have problems because all css and js are loaded from mobile part. This is why I try to stop the rewrite for a specific file type (css and js)                                       # execute redirect 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/ca-eng/pages/storesection/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|js)
RewriteRule (.*) http://mobile.mysite.com$1 [R,L]                           Let me know if I am on the right track

Comment: ok I made another change to avoid redirecting css,j,images. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your fix Anubhava! We just had a staging deployment and our service provider claims that this code version (full code) works except the files exclusion row that breaks the folder exclusion too. Thanks in advance for your support!

Comment: You may have some conflicting rules below this. Try adding `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` above this rule.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your fast reply! Just added the suggested row. Let me know if I put it in the right spot.